# Error with date insert - Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string

Tags: sql-server

I have a stored procedure I am building where it fails when I try to insert data. This is the insert:

```
INSERT INTO [AdminDB].[dbo].[DEFECTS_MAINTENANCE]([DATE], [Year], [Month], [Total])
    SELECT
        CONVERT(DATE, getdate()) AS 'Date',
        DATENAME(yyyy, getdate()) AS 'Year',
        DATENAME(mm, getdate()) AS 'Month',
        COUNT([BG_BUG_ID]) AS 'Total'
    FROM 
        [maint_maintenance_db].[td].[BUG]
    WHERE
        YEAR(DETECTION_DATE]) = YEAR(getdate()) 
        AND MONTH([DETECTION_DATE]) =  MONTH(getdate())
```

When I execute the code above I get this error:

> Msg 241, Level 16, State 1, Procedure usp_TC_TESTCYCL_ID_COUNT_PILOT_UCPATH, Line 10
>   Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string.

When I change the code to use CAST it works, but does not return the values properly. Below is the code:

```
INSERT INTO [AdminDB].[dbo].[DEFECTS_MAINTENANCE]([DATE], [Year], [Month], [Total])
    SELECT 
        CAST(getdate() AS Date),
        CAST(getdate() AS datetime),
        CAST(getdate() AS datetime), 
        COUNT([BG_BUG_ID]) AS 'Total'
    FROM 
        [maint_maintenance_db].[td].[BUG]
    WHERE
        YEAR(DETECTION_DATE]) = YEAR(getdate()) 
        AND MONTH([DETECTION_DATE]) =  MONTH(getdate())
```

How can I get this to work? Any help is appreciated!

Thanks

Comment: Are you triying to get "MONTH name" or "MOnth numer"?, what is the column definition for your table DEFECTS_MAINTENANCE

Comment: For starters you are missing a comma in your `INSERT` statement between the last two columns.

Comment: What datatype is `DETECTION_DATE` ?

Comment: Please post the DDL (definition) for the DEFECTS_MAINTENANCE table. Seems as if the Year or Month columns is in fact a datetime or something. You are casting those to Datetime in your INSERT that works.  Your one that doesn't, the DATENAME function returns a string (NVARCHAR).

Answer (score 1):

It looks like [Month] is of type datetime.
That's why the cast works:
CAST(getdate() as datetime)

In your INSERT using convert you are trying to implicitly convert a 2 digit number to a date and that is failing.

```
,datename(mm,getdate()) AS 'Month'
```

Change Month to be integer or char(2) and you should be all set.